# If I put a <span> on a new line, stars will change position

Tags: html, css

Hi I have following code:

```css
.fotoRating {
  color: #c5c5c5;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #a2a2a2;
}

.fotoRating .selectedStars {
  color: #e7711b;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="fotoRating">
  <span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span>

  <div class="selectedStars" style="width:150px;">
    <span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I put  `span` on a new line, the stars will break: http://jsfiddle.net/mozkomor05/6hkpj0L4/1/

I think there is a small mistake, but I can't find it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want stars to not break?

Comment: Yes (sorry for my english I'm from Czech republic)

Comment: Just change the width: 150px to width: 300px ?

Comment: But I need to have selected only a specific part of the stars.

Comment: Use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6hkpj0L4/3/. Change the width and you can choose how many selected stars you have.

Comment: @Kushtrim Posting an actual answer (with the code in the answer) would benefit the community far more than a JS Fiddle which will one day disappear.

Comment: @jpaugh The question seemed so simple and I thought it would be too much to create a post just for it.

Comment: @Kushtrim If it's worth answering at all, then it's worth doing it well. Why deprive future readers of your answer? If it contributes unique value compared to the other answers, add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @webdevdani approach works, it doesn't give the same result. Which is why I suggest this:

```
.fotoRating span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

This way the browser thinks they're cells and ignore the white space between the elements, while preserving the functionality

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/6hkpj0L4/4/

Comment: No problem. Glad it works

Answer (score 1):

The set width on your selected stars container is causing the characters to break into another line to fit. If you want to prevent line-breaks, add this rule to `.selectedStars`

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: Forked codepen: http://jsfiddle.net/1kyehk8p/

Comment: Thanks, but now width of selected stars isn't exact

Comment: @DavidMoškoř Can you elaborate? Width of the stars, or the line? You would have to change the width on .selectedStars to change the width of the line

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to have different colors on the stars, you don't need two rows of them. You can just add a class to each star as needed:

```css
.fotoRating {
  color: #c5c5c5;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #a2a2a2;
}

.is-selected {
    color: #e7711b;
 }
```

```html
<div class="fotoRating">
    <span class="is-selected">&#9733;</span>
    <span class="is-selected">&#9733;</span>
    <span class="is-selected">&#9733;</span>
    <span>&#9733;</span>
    <span>&#9733;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a fixed `height` on `.selectedStarts`. When you decrease the width to show a fewer number of stars, the stars are wrapping and your container is defaulting to `height: auto;` therefore showing all it's content.

Using a fixed width (here I used 70px) in combination with the `overflow: hidden;` which you already had in place does the job.

```css
.fotoRating {
  color: #c5c5c5;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #a2a2a2;
}

.fotoRating .selectedStars {
  color: #e7711b;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height; 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fotoRating">
  <span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span>

  <div class="selectedStars" style="width:150px;">
    <span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span><span>&#9733;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```